# How to show options under select (Angular material 7)?

Tags: angular, html-select, angular-material2, angular-material-6

How to show options under select (Angular material 7)?
[image]

Something like default select:

[image]

Comment: Please see revised answer, changed click event to the mat-form-field and adjusted the setTimeout to ,0

Comment: Why do you want to make a material design component behave in a non-material way? If you don't want material design, use a different component library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "correct" answer is to use the `disableOptionCentering` on your mat-select, but even this only prevents the placeholder from being covered and does not mimic the basic native select.

```
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" disableOptionCentering>
```

It is strongly frowned upon to do DOM manipulation of the native element in Angular, but this unfortunately, is the only way I have found to do stuff like this...

- Hopefully someone will post a true "Angular" way to do this kind of
  stuff as I find myself manipulating the material library for these
  types of reasons.

You will need to wrap your options with a div wrapper and assign a templateRef `#matOptionDiv` so that you can use this in your component to grab the parent element(s) of your option drop down which is the CDK overlay.

```
<div #matOptionDiv>
   <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
   </mat-option>
</div>
```

Then use the click event on `mat-form-field` to trigger a method in your component to align the overlay

```
<mat-form-field (click)="positionDropDown()">
```

Then in your component use `@ViewChild` to grab the templateRef

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('matOptionDiv') _matOptionDiv:any;
```

Then create your method to calculate new `top` value on the overlay and assign it... the setTimout is necessary to trigger change with the digest cycle.

```
positionDropDown(){
  let offsetY = 
  this._matOptionDiv.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.top

  setTimeout(()=>{this._matOptionDiv.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.top = parseInt(offsetY.slice(0, -2))+40+'px'},0)
  }
```

This is a very "hacky" solution and is not pretty, hopefully someone at some point will post an answer with a true "Angular" solution to this question.

- Unfortunately there are calculations happening in the source of the mat-select to programmatically define the top of the overlay
  based on the viewable area via `_calculateOverlayOffsetY`... none of this is exposed in the API so I
  am not able to manipulate it "correctly" and I fear DOM manipulation may
  be the only way.

https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/6d7f41739207e469e626963d64e661401629902d/src/lib/select/select.ts#L1154

Here is Stackblitz for your review.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nafuur?embed=1&file=app/select-overview-example.ts

**Revision**

I did some more research on this and DOM manipulation is acceptable in angular as long as you are using `Renderer2` as it interfaces with the DOM adapter and updates the DOM "appropriately"... making the DOM changes platform independent.

Please reference this youTube video for more information.

[Can't Touch This! What not to do to the DOM by Max NgWizard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWmqiYDrnDc)

---

Stackblitz code update below

```
import {Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('matOptionDiv') _matOptionDiv:ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

 positionDropDown() {
    let offsetY = this._matOptionDiv.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.top;

    setTimeout(() => {
      // this._matOptionDiv.nativeElement.parentElement.parentElement.style.top = parseInt(offsetY.slice(0, -2))+40+'px'},0)
      this.renderer.setStyle(this.renderer.parentNode(this.renderer.parentNode(this._matOptionDiv.nativeElement)), 'top', parseInt(offsetY.slice(0, -2)) + 40 + 'px');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Docs where you got the screenshots from give a pretty comprehensive overview of how to include this component, just make sure you press the

```
<>
```

at the top right of the example for the code that created it. If it's something specific you're struggling with post the error(s) you're getting

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview