# Angular Material Dropdown Styling: Trim Left and Right Side in CSS

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I am trying to get Angular Material Select to look like basic dropdown. We applied `disableOptionCentering`, still seeing dropdown list options expand from left and right side (see Current picture below). The ideal picture should have the left and right sides slimmed down, How to conduct this ?

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview

```
<h4>Basic mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select disableOptionCentering>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**Currently looks as this:**

Need to trim left and right side, margin /or padding appropriately to be vertical

[image]

**Goal picture:**

[image]

Comment: Instead of <mat-select> if you use <select> you should get the native version. That's what you want if I understand correctly

Comment: correct, thats what I am trying, amend the native version to look like ideal picture above, for some reason it does not look like that, even though UX team built this with Adobe angular material, sure the option exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how they achieved it in official documentation of material design but I guess you might need to get some css fixed for this as it is not showing material styling. You can just add your custom css to style it like angular material.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
  <select matNativeControl required>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Your question is also answered on this thread [How to show options under select (Angular material 7)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376946/how-to-show-options-under-select-angular-material-7)